# Change first ng-options text in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown with various versions. For the first version, I'd like to add "latest" to the displayed text on the dropdown only, is there a simple way to do that?

HTML:

```
<select ng-model='selectedVersion'
        ng-options="version.name for version in versions"
        class="form-control">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.versions = [
    { name: "3.0" },
    { name: "2.0" },
    { name: "1.0" },
]
$scope.selectedVersion = $scope.versions[0];
```

So right now the dropdown shows "3.0", "2.0", "1.0", but I would like to have the first option be "3.0 (latest)".

I can change the object name directly, but I'm passing the selected object to another scope and would cause issues, so this won't be stable:

```
$scope.versions[0].name += " (latest)";
```

I just want "latest" to be show inside the dropdown if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is always going to have latest first, you can do this:

```
<select ng-model='selectedVersion'
    ng-options="(version.name == versions[0].name ? 'latest' : version.name) for version in versions"
    class="form-control">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using `version == versions[0]`, I think it's the same object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is better wraps into a namespace for avoid problems between scopes

#### js

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  var versions = [{ name: "3.0" }, { name: "2.0" }, { name: "1.0" },];
  $scope.prop = {
    "value": versions[0], 
    "values": versions 
  };
}
```

#### html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v.name for v in prop.values">
  </select>

</div>
```

[Preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/suz49nIcnfc5ZlSfvC91?p=preview)